# How can I get a string between two quotes in a batch file?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a string in a batch file, of the structure

`[[status]]:{"01bcd123-1234-5678-0000-abcdefghijkl": "11"}`

I need to get just the `01bcd123-1234-5678-0000-abcdefghijkl` out of it, but trying to use " as a delimiter doesn't turn out well. \ and ^ don't seem to escape it properly.

`set i=1`

`set "x!i!=%x:"=" & set /A i+=1 & set "x!i!=%"`

Is what I have with x being the whole string, attempting to parse it into x1, x2 etc with " as the delimiter.

What is a proper way to split this string, using " as the delimiter?

Edit: Powershell tag is because I am running the script as part of a larger orchestration in Powershell and could export the functionality of the batch script into it if necessary.

Comment: Since you tagged the question with `powershell`, I would definitely recommend using PowerShell rather than `cmd.exe` shell script (batch).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two approaches. The first one doesn't mess with the `for` syntax format, but it's risky - too much dependence on the string (the quotes are actually stripped by `%%~`). The second one is an ugly non-intuitive syntax, but actually delimits by quotes:

```
set "string=[[status]]:{"01bcd123-1234-5678-0000-abcdefghijkl": "11"}"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:{" %%a in ("%string%") do @echo %%~a
for /f tokens^=2delims^=^" %%a in ("%string%") do @echo %%a
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, the self-expanding code you have posted works fine, given that you have got [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) enabled, by having put the statement `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` placed before. The string of interest is then stored in variable `x2`. Note that when the script terminates, `x2` (like all the other `x#` variables as well) is no longer available since an implicit `endlocal` is executed then. To avoid that, place `endlocal & set "x2=%x2%"` in the last line:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Define string to parse:
set "x=[[status]]:{"01bcd123-1234-5678-0000-abcdefghijkl": "11"}"

rem // Enable delayed expansion:
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem // Initialise index counter:
set i=1
rem // Split string using self-expanding code:
set "x!i!=%x:"=" & set /A i+=1 & set "x!i!=%" & rem // (unbalanced `"`!)
rem // Display all `x#` variables:
set x
rem // Make `x2` survive the `endlocal` barrier:
endlocal & set "x2=%x2%"
rem // Return the retrieved value:
echo(%x2%
```

However, I would most probably use a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html), but not with `"` as delimiter since the syntax appears quite odd then; rather I would use `:`, `{`, `}` and <kbd>SPACE</kbd> as delimiters. But I would remove the prefix `[[status]]` in advance:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Define string to parse:
set "x=[[status]]:{"01bcd123-1234-5678-0000-abcdefghijkl": "11"}"
rem /* At first, split off everything up to the first occurrence of `]]`;
rem    if there is no such prefix, there is no harm, because nothing happens;
rem    then extract the first token that is delimited by `:`, `{`, `}` or space;
rem    that way there may even be spaces around the `:` or around `{` or `}`;
rem    then return it with surrounding quotation marks removed (`~`-modifier): */
for /F "tokens=1 eol=: delims=:{} " %%I in ("%x:*]]=%") do echo(%%~I
```

*N. B.:*
The odd-looking syntax `echo(` is not a typo, it is actually the only safe way to echo an arbitrary string (even `on`, `off` or `/?`); take a look at [this external thread](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=774) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged PowerShell, you can use the following regex, but I am not sure you want PowerShell based on the question.

```
[regex]::Match('[[status]]:{"01bcd123-1234-5678-0000-abcdefghijkl": "11"}','(?<=")[^"]+(?=")').Value
```

Split regex can also work:

```
('[[status]]:{"01bcd123-1234-5678-0000-abcdefghijkl": "11"}' -split '"')[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you stick with a batch file, [Stephan's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57296846/45375) is definitely the simplest and fastest solution.

Needless to say, if you port your batch file to PowerShell, you'll have vastly more functionality at your disposal.

You can even harness that functionality from a batch file via [PowerShell's CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), by calling `powershell.exe` (Windows PowerShell) or `pwsh.exe` (POwerShell Core), but that comes with two caveats:

- Doing so creates a PowerShell child process, whose startup time is not insignificant.
- Getting nested quoting right can be a challenge, as shown below.

Here's **a solution that calls PowerShell's CLI from a batch file**, applying the `-split` technique from [AdminOfThings' helfpul answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57296802/45375); again, this solution would be overkill in the case at hand, but the approach **may be of interest if you need to perform tasks that simply cannot be done in the batch language or would be too cumbersome.**

```
@echo off
setlocal

:: # The input text.
set txt=[[status]]:{"01bcd123-1234-5678-0000-abcdefghijkl": "11"}

:: # Call the PowerShell CLI to extract the token of interest and save the
:: # result in variable %id%.
:: # In PowerShell code, the equivalent would be:
:: #    $id = ($txt -split '"')[1]
for /f %%i in ('powershell -noprofile -c "('%txt:"=\"%' -split '\""')[1]"') do set id=%%i

:: # Echo the result.
echo %id%
```

Note the need to `\`-escape the `"` chars. embedded in `%txt%`, via substitution `%txt:"=\"%`, and the need for an *additional* `"` char. after `\"` in `'\""'` so as to prevent the `for` command from breaking.